# Pygame, i need to have obstacles repeat randomly

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
import random

screen_width = 500
screen_height = 500

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255,0,0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)


fps = 30


#the size of our player square
playerSize = 50

#rectangles get declared with x, y, w, h
obstacle = [0, 0, 350, 50]
obstacle2 = [150, 0, 410, 50]


obstacleMoveSpeed = 5
#how fast to move obstalce down







def check_collision(playerRect, obstacleRect):
    #convert rectangles into x,y,w,h
    playerX = playerRect[0]
    playerY = playerRect[1]
    playerWidth = playerRect[2]
    playerHeight = playerRect[3]

    obstacleX = obstacle[0]
    obstacleY = obstacle[1]
    obstacleWidth = obstacle[2]
    obstacleHeight = obstacle[3]

    obstacleX2 = obstacle2[0]
    obstacleY2 = obstacle2[1]
    obstacleWidth2 = obstacle2[2]
    obstacleHeight2 = obstacle2[3]



    #get the right left top and bottom
    myRight = playerX + playerWidth
    myLeft = playerX
    myTop = playerY
    myBottom = playerY + playerHeight

    otherRight = obstacleX + obstacleWidth
    otherLeft = obstacleX
    otherTop = obstacleY
    otherBottom = obstacleY + obstacleHeight

    otherRight2 = obstacleX2 + obstacleWidth2
    otherLeft2 = obstacleX2
    otherTop2 = obstacleY2
    otherBottom2 = obstacleY2 + obstacleHeight2

    #now the collision code
    collision = True

    if ((myRight < otherLeft) or (myLeft > otherRight) or (myBottom < otherTop) or (myTop > otherBottom)):
        collision = False

    if ((myRight < otherLeft2) or (myLeft > otherRight2) or (myBottom < otherTop2) or (myTop > otherBottom2)):
        collision = False

    return collision

"""def randomOb(randomize, obstacle, obstacle2):



                if randomize == 0:
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, obstacle)
                        obstacle = [0, 0, 350, 50]
                        randomize = random.randrange(0,2)
                if randomize == 1:
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, obstacle2)
                        obstacle2 = [150, 0, 410, 50]
                        randomize = random.randrange(0,2)

                randomize = random.randrange(0,2)
                return randomize"""

def game_loop():


        randomize = random.randrange(0,2)
        playerRect = [(screen_width / 2)-(playerSize/2), 400, playerSize, playerSize]
        #(screen_width / 2)-(playerSize/2) just figures out how to center the player
        while 1:

                for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                                exit()
                        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                                        playerRect = [(screen_width * 0.2)-(playerSize/2), 400, playerSize, playerSize]
                                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                                        playerRect = [(screen_width * 0.8)-(playerSize/2), 400, playerSize, playerSize]
                        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                                        playerRect = [(screen_width / 2)-(playerSize/2), 400, playerSize, playerSize]







                #move obstacle downward
                obstacle[1] = obstacle[1] + obstacleMoveSpeed
                obstacle2[1] = obstacle2[1] + obstacleMoveSpeed



                if (check_collision(playerRect, obstacle)):
                        print("COLLISION")



                #drawing code
                screen.fill(black)


                #draw our player
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, playerRect)

                pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, obstacle)

                """randomOb(randomize, obstacle, obstacle2)
                if obstacle[1] > 500 or obstacle2[1] > 500:
                        randomize = random.randrange(0,2)
                        randomOb(randomize, obstacle, obstacle2)"""


                pygame.display.update()

                clock.tick(fps)


game_loop()
```

I need to have my obstacles repeat randomly. right now i only have 2 obstacles but will add on. I would like to keep object orientation out of this please. Whenever i try to do this it will either call the randomize variable it will call my obstacles a bunch of times, or it will call one obstacle but then not repeat with another obstacle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your same obstacle to repeat randomly the the simplest way to do it would be to add a clause in your game loop checking to see if the object is off the screen, as such:

```
import pygame
import random

screen_width = 500
screen_height = 500

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255,0,0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

fps = 30


#the size of our player square
playerSize = 50

#rectangles get declared with x, y, w, h
obstacle = [0, 0, 350, 50]


obstacleMoveSpeed = 5
#how fast to move obstalce down


def check_collision(playerRect, obstacleRect):
    #convert rectangles into x,y,w,h
    playerX = playerRect[0]
    playerY = playerRect[1]
    playerWidth = playerRect[2]
    playerHeight = playerRect[3]

    obstacleX = obstacle[0]
    obstacleY = obstacle[1]
    obstacleWidth = obstacle[2]
    obstacleHeight = obstacle[3]

    #get the right left top and bottom
    myRight = playerX + playerWidth
    myLeft = playerX
    myTop = playerY
    myBottom = playerY + playerHeight

    otherRight = obstacleX + obstacleWidth
    otherLeft = obstacleX
    otherTop = obstacleY
    otherBottom = obstacleY + obstacleHeight

    #now the collision code
    collision = True

    if ((myRight < otherLeft) or (myLeft > otherRight) or (myBottom < otherTop) or (myTop > otherBottom)):
        collision = False


    return collision

"""def randomOb(randomize, obstacle, obstacle2):



                if randomize == 0:
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, obstacle)
                        obstacle = [0, 0, 350, 50]
                        randomize = random.randrange(0,2)
                if randomize == 1:
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, obstacle2)
                        obstacle2 = [150, 0, 410, 50]
                        randomize = random.randrange(0,2)

                randomize = random.randrange(0,2)
                return randomize"""

def game_loop():


        randomize = random.randrange(0,2)
        playerRect = [(screen_width / 2)-(playerSize/2), 400, playerSize, playerSize]
        screen_padding = random.randint(0, 100)
        #(screen_width / 2)-(playerSize/2) just figures out how to center the player
        while 1:

                for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                                exit()
                        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                                        playerRect = [(screen_width * 0.2)-(playerSize/2), 400, playerSize, playerSize]
                                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                                        playerRect = [(screen_width * 0.8)-(playerSize/2), 400, playerSize, playerSize]
                        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                                        playerRect = [(screen_width / 2)-(playerSize/2), 400, playerSize, playerSize]







                #move obstacle downward
                obstacle[1] = obstacle[1] + obstacleMoveSpeed



                if (check_collision(playerRect, obstacle)):
                        print("COLLISION")
                if obstacle[1] > screen_height + screen_padding:
                        obstacle[1] = -50
                        screen_padding = random.randint(0, 100)
                        orientation = bool(random.getrandbits(1))
                        if orientation:
                                obstacle[0] = 0
                        else:
                                obstacle[0] = 150



                #drawing code
                screen.fill(black)


                #draw our player
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, playerRect)

                pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, obstacle)

                """randomOb(randomize, obstacle, obstacle2)
                if obstacle[1] > 500 or obstacle2[1] > 500:
                        randomize = random.randrange(0,2)
                        randomOb(randomize, obstacle, obstacle2)"""


                pygame.display.update()

                clock.tick(fps)


game_loop()
```

This makes it so that the block goes to the top of the screen when it gets to the bottom, but not sometimes it will wait a little distance, changing the frequency of the loop. It will also randomly change the orientation of the obstacle

Comment: Examples would be greatly appreciated! And would this work with more then just 2 obstacles? Thank you for your response!

Comment: What you would do is create a separate statement for each block. So, yes, you could apply it to as many blocks as you wanted, but the idea is that you only have as many blocks as you want on the screen at the same time.

Comment: I added the padding (which would obviously have to be pre-defined at the top). Your game has some bugs in it, so I'm not sure what you're doing with your method. Do you know why your blocks are so glitchy and how to fix it? I noticed that drawing the blocks was inside of an `if` statement, which is a huge no-no. If you fix that then randomizing orientation will be easy.

Comment: Well i am only trying to have one obstacle on the screen at a time, where it falls down towards the player block, but i need to have the obstacles repeat randomly so the game can not be predicted and form a little bit of a challenge.

Comment: Oops, the code that i stuck up there was an attempt to make them repeat, give me a second and i will fix that.

Comment: Ah. Then you're going to want to ditch `obstacle2` and work only with `obstacle`. After all, you can't make an infinite number of blocks (and if you could, you shouldn't and wouldn't want to)

Comment: Ok i fixed those glitches.

Comment: So i have tried placing all of my obstacle coordinates and width in one list `obstacle` but it gave me an error when i tried to access only those four numbers

Comment: You're going to need to delete everything related to `obstacle2`. What was the error?

Comment: I forgot what the error said but it was something like: "Rect error" i am fairly new to python and pygame so its very likely i tried slicing it wrong. I will go and delete everything related too `obstacle2`

Comment: I updated my answer. If I'm understanding your question, this code should work for you. If you have any questions, let me know.

Comment: The error was "Rect argument is invalid" I tried just inputting the actual slice into the rect statement. `pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, obstacle[3:7])` This is probably very incorrect.

Comment: Great! In that case an accepted answer would be appreciated! Please let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Actually i do, if i wanted to have two rects in a single obstacle how would i do that? For example i have one obstacle rect on the left side of the player rect and one  obstacle rect on the right side of the player rect. Again i am new to python so i apologize for all these questions.

Comment: If you want them on the screen at the same time, then the best way to do it would be to create another object, sort of like you had before. You could, technically create it in one object, but it would be unwieldy. A good rule of thumb is to have one object for every item on the screen at a time.

Comment: So i have been trying to get it so there are four different obstacles that cycle through the random obstacle rotation, but it will place two different obstacles on the screen at the same time, sometimes in the same x coordinate and sometimes in different y coordinates.